# How to build a empty basicblock and insert a Instruction in the front?

Tags: llvm

I write a function to create a empty basicblock:

```
BasicBlock* createEmptyBlock(){
    llvm::LLVMContext context;
    IRBuilder<> builder(context);
    Function *mainFunction;
    mainFunction->setDoesNotReturn();
    BasicBlock* mainblock = BasicBlock::Create(context, "entrypoint", mainFunction);
    return mainblock;
}
```

but when insert my instruction in the front of this mainblock:

```
 Instruction *newBInst_0 = setBranchInst(F, inst, 1);//product a inst
                            llvm::BasicBlock *bb;
                            bb=createEmptyBlock();                      
                            newBInst_0->insertBefore(bb->front());//there are some errors
                            bb->insertInto(&F,&block);
```

I found some errors when I insert
What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to stop **creating a context and builder instance** each time you call `createEmptyBlock`. Just one context is required per thread and in general one builder instance so llvm helps you keep track of where to insert ir. This really helps with method calls such as `builder.GetInsertBlock()`

Also you don't need to attach a block to a function each time you create one. You're function could now look like this

```
BasicBlock* createEmptyBlock(){
    BasicBlock* mainblock = BasicBlock::Create(context, "entrypoint");
    return mainblock;
}
```

supposing you'd want all your block labels to be prefixed with "entrypoint". Plus, the function body is nearly a one-liner. Why not just inline it like so

```
Instruction *newBInst_0 = setBranchInst(F, inst, 1);//product a inst
llvm::BasicBlock *bb = BasicBlock::Create(context, "entrypoint");                      
bb->insertInto(&F,&block);
newBInst_0->insertBefore(bb->front());
```

supposing your `builder` and `context` instances are global variables (which I recommend they should).

It also looks like you're not using your `builder` instance much. Try exploring some of its methods such as `builder.SetInsertPoint` and `builder.CreateCondBr`